# Not able to force index on mysql index

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, greatest-n-per-group

I'm trying to optimize a query, but explain query gives that mysql is not using any index.

This is my query:

```
explain
 SELECT t1.* 

    FROM crypto_screener.prices as t1 FORCE INDEX (PRIMARY)

    where t1.id = (
      select t2.id
      from (select *
              from
              crypto_screener.prices FORCE INDEX (allfilters)
              where date > '2017-12-07'
              ) as t2
      where t2.symbol = t1.symbol
      order by t2.id desc
      limit 1
      )
;
```

This is `show index from prices;`

```
Table   Non_unique  Key_name    Seq_in_index    Column_name Collation   Cardinality Sub_part    Packed  Null    Index_type  Comment Index_comment
prices  0   PRIMARY 1   id  A   57718   NULL    NULL        BTREE       
prices  0   priceid 1   id  A   57718   NULL    NULL        BTREE       
prices  1   pricefilters    1   symbol  A   369 NULL    NULL    YES BTREE       
prices  1   pricefilters    2   date    A   57718   NULL    NULL    YES BTREE       
prices  1   datefilters 1   date    A   506 NULL    NULL    YES BTREE       
prices  1   symbolfilters   1   symbol  A   421 NULL    NULL    YES BTREE       
prices  1   allfilters  1   id  A   57718   NULL    NULL        BTREE       
prices  1   allfilters  2   symbol  A   57718   NULL    NULL    YES BTREE       
prices  1   allfilters  3   date    A   57718   NULL    NULL    YES BTREE
```

The query doesn't run now with the amount of data inside the table. How can I optimize this?

Comment: You can't use `allfilters` here (as its an index over 3 colums and date is not the first column in the index, so basically this index is useless as you already have an index over the id) Can you use `datefilters`?

Comment: @RolandStarke Yes, datefilters works on t2

Comment: Great. Is it enough to boost the performance? I can't wrap my head around what this query is selecting. It would be interesting to know.

Comment: @RolandStarke the table prices has a price of n symbols for t dates. The query is selecting for each symbol, the most recent row, which contains the last price (highest id). With the datefilters, it isn't enough to run the query yet.

Comment: this is right for the subquery t2. @O.Jones I explained on a comment above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want the row with the highest `id` value for each distinct `symbol` value within the particular date range.

Here's how you do that.  First, use a subquery to get a list of `symbol, id` values showing the highest `id` value for each symbol, for the subset of your table with the desired dates.

```
                 SELECT symbol, MAX(id) id
                   FROM prices
                  WHERE date >  '2017-12-07'
                  GROUP BY symbol
```

This subquery can be optimized by a compound index on `date, symbol, id`. Why? It random-accesses the index to the first eligible date, then scans it sequentially looking for distinct values of symbol and id.

You can test that subquery. Make sure it's giving you reasonable results.

Then use it in a main query, like so:

```
 SELECT t1.*
   FROM prices t1
   JOIN (
                 SELECT symbol, MAX(id) id
                   FROM prices
                  WHERE date >  '2017-12-07'
                  GROUP BY symbol
        ) t2 ON t1.id = t2.id AND t1.symbol = t2.symbol
```

Now, because your `id` values are all unique, you can simplify the `ON` condition by leaving out `AND t1.symbol = t2.symbol`.

This should, with the proper compound index, run very quickly indeed.

**Pro tip 1**: Don't create extra indexes just for good measure. Make sure they are there to help some query you need to run.

**Pro tip 2**: `date > '2017-12-07'` excludes rows at midnight on the date you named, but takes all rows after midnight on that date. If the datatype of your `date` column is `DATETIME`, using `>` is probably incorrect. If the datatype is `DATE`, your filter means the same thing as `date >= '2017-12-08'`.

**Pro tip 3**: trying to force MySQL's query planner to use certain indexes is usually counterproductive. Much better is making sure you have the correct indexes.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I was struggling with this problem for a while. Very impressive and elegant solution. Congratulations, I'm impressed.